# Android app to search a specific text in all telegram chats/group chats

Tags: java, android, telegram

I want to create an android app that has a search box. When the user starts typing text, the app searches for matching text in all the telegram chats/group chats and creates jump links instead of going through chats one by one.

I was going through the telegram bot api but dont understand how to implement it in my android app. My IDE is Android studio. I came across the following api but don't understand the https url that I should be using

(messages.search#8614ef68 flags:# peer:InputPeer q:string from_id:flags.0?InputUser filter:MessagesFilter min_date:int max_date:int offset_id:int add_offset:int limit:int max_id:int min_id:int hash:int = messages.Messages;)

I just need to create jump links to be able to jump to that text in the chat in telegram. For example, if I search for "how are you?" then it should create jump links for all chats that contain this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all. Telegram bot, should nothing to do with your Android application. Bot is a backend service, which working with a particular chat. You need to create bot with Server with few simple actions **to fetch all messages from all chats, where this bot is added**.

2) Information above should be forward to *my android app* as you mentioned above. You need to create few requests on backend system to download it to the application.

3) Later in the Android app you can fetch it from your backend service and perform search. Filtered result could be added to list, and to jump to the chat you will implement `Intent` call to Telegram app.

**Please note**. As you can, it's not a simple task. Another point, your bot should be added to every chat, to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mate. Is there any other way i can achieve the problem without using the bot concept?

Comment: @Shamoelhussain Let me explain, what you are trying to do. You are trying to hack application and pull a sensitive data from it. In 2019.  Do you expect it would be easy?